# How to get the gerrit code review link when we do git push to gerrit repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to setup gerrit code review server . I have installed the gerrit server and I am able to access it on my local host `localhost:8080` 
I have also installed `gerrit git review` . 
After committing changes of a file ,when I do `git push origin master` I get this

```
dev> git push origin master
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 621 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://newbie@localhost:29418/dev.git
   ac19936..de7d7ea  master -> master
```

When I do `git review` I get this

```
dev> git review
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)
remote: Processing changes: new: 1, refs: 1, done    
remote: 
remote: New Changes:
remote:   http://localhost:8080/6 this is a check on gerrit code review with git review
remote: 
To ssh://newbie@localhost:29418/dev.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/publish/master
```

Only when I do a `git review` I am getting the link `http://localhost:8080/6` to the code review on localhost.
I want to get that code review link even when I do a `git push` . How can I get that ? Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
git push gerrit HEAD:refs/publish/master
```

This solved my problem.
I got this solution when I ran `git review -v`  This displayed all the commands that are run in the process of review .

```
dev> git review -v
2015-05-26 12:59:32.789433 Running: git log --color=never --oneline HEAD^1..HEAD
2015-05-26 12:59:32.794065 Running: git remote
2015-05-26 12:59:32.797142 Running: git branch -a --color=never
2015-05-26 12:59:32.800575 Running: git rev-parse --show-toplevel --git-dir
2015-05-26 12:59:32.803797 Running: git remote update gerrit
Fetching gerrit
2015-05-26 12:59:32.870035 Running: git rev-parse HEAD
2015-05-26 12:59:32.873419 Running: git show-ref --quiet --verify refs/remotes/gerrit/master
2015-05-26 12:59:32.876519 Running: git rebase -p -i remotes/gerrit/master
2015-05-26 12:59:33.637414 Running: git reset --hard 5e0c601b83d598a52c8234d4ef4213acce824dea
2015-05-26 12:59:33.745906 Running: git config --get color.ui
2015-05-26 12:59:33.749583 Running: git log --color=always --decorate --oneline HEAD --not --remotes=gerrit
2015-05-26 12:59:33.754085 Running: git branch --color=never
2015-05-26 12:59:33.757454 Running: git log HEAD^1..HEAD
Using local branch name "master" for the topic of the change submitted
2015-05-26 12:59:33.766298 Running: git push gerrit HEAD:refs/publish/master
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2)
remote: Processing changes: new: 1, refs: 1, done    
remote: 
remote: New Changes:
remote:   http://localhost:8080/7 another checking for checking git review
remote: 
To ssh://newbie@localhost:29418/dev.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/publish/master
2015-05-26 12:59:34.139211 Running: git rev-parse --show-toplevel --git-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **git push origin master** you are pushing **bypass** Gerrit.

You should push to gerrit like this format:

```
git push origin master:refs/for/master
```

Then you will get remote url like

```
remote:  http://localhost/c/dev/+/YOUR ChangeID  YOUR Commit Message
```